# Return the owner of a variable - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So I have objects that in turn have sprites associated to them. a snippet of my Object class:

```
import SpriteKit

 class Block {

 var sprite : ColourSprite

}
```

So as you can see, it has a variable that is in fact a SKSprite (ColourSprite is my custom class that inherits from SKSpriteNode).

Now, at some points during the game, these sprites are deleted (i.e sprite.removeFromParent()), but the objects are obviously still somewhere.

I want to be able to send the objects to garbage collection once their sprites are gone. I am thinking that I can do something like sprite.getOwner() but I can't seem to find it. Is this possible?

The only other option I can think of is to manually check all objects and check each one's sprite but I feel that is long and wasteful.

Comment: Are you keeping a reference of any kind to the "Block" objects? Is something keeping it? Do you have an array with the blocks or something? What's the purpose of wrapping the spride inside a Block class?

Comment: yes, so I have in GameScence for example: let block1 = Block(). I suppose the purpose of it is when I create multiple block sprites I don't want to repeat lines of code when setting up the physics and stuff so I kept all that function within the class.

Comment: Why do you say "the objects are obviously still somewhere"? If you think you are releasing all referenced to an object and it is not getting freed (eg. destructor not called), then you probably have a circular reference.

Comment: I say that as the deleted sprite isn't the actual object.

Comment: The thing is that, you might have a wrapper class for your sprites with just convenience methods, but if you don't have a reference to the block object itself, its probably disappearing as soon as its queued in your sprite manager. This is because when you add the sprite, you are only adding the reference to the sprite itself, but the block wrapper object is not being referenced by anything so its automatically released. In other words, as long as you DONT keep a reference to the block class, it will be released automatically.

Comment: Ah I see. Okay. I don't really need the reference to the Block, so I could try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the `Block`s are still in memory by using Xcode 8.3's new debug panel.

[image]

[image]

Just after you remove your sprites pause the program and go to that panel. See if there is any `Block` instances in the left panel. If there is, click on it to check what is retaining it.

If for example your `GameScene` is retaining the `Block`, you go to your `GameScene` and find the property. Then you can just set that to `nil` after you remove your sprite.